# Is the wedge product of two non-vanishing differential forms non-vanishing?

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Is the wedge product of two non-vanishing differential forms non-vanishing? Suppose that $w$ and $v$ are two non-vanishing wedge product on $V$, and the degree of $w$ and $v$ adds to the dimension of $V$.

Comment: How about $dx\wedge dx$?

Comment: As another example, consider the wedge product of two-forms in $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: I am sorry, but I have edited the question.

Comment: Moishe's example still works, for the appropriate choice of $V$.

Comment: Think of the linear algebra version of this question in $\mathbb R^3$. In this case, you are thinking of a 1-form and a 2-form. By using the metric, you can think of the 2-form as specifying a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ without specifying a basis for that plane (this is not quite true -- think about it for a while, it's a worthwhile thing to understand). The 1-form can be thought as dual to a vector. Then, the wedge of these things is non-vanishing when the span of all of them is $\mathbb{R}^3$, but vanishes if the line is contained in the plane.

Comment: The short form of my comment: study the linear case first. The rest will follow.